# Background Image Not showing in Section

Tags: html, css

When I use the following code the background image isn't being displayed are there any prerequisites to display a background image ?

```
<section class="starter"></section>


 .starter
    {
     background-image:url("Assets/Images/Section.jpg");
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
     width:100%;
     height: 100px;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
    }
```

Comment: What does your `console` say? Is the image not found perhaps? This code looks fine apart from your comment not starting correctly. Well, and the unnecessary `top` and `left` values but okay.

Comment: there could be a lot of reasons. can you reproduce that in a jsfiddle?

Comment: You have a comment there. Where is the beginning of it?

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon or in a SO snippet?

Comment: @somethinghere There is absolutely no output,like just a blank screen

Comment: You will have to be more specific and post us your more complete code. Please try to recreate the issue using an SO snippet (the document with the `<>` icon in it when editing a post) and use an image from, say, `placehold.it` to be sure your image exists. This will help us help you.

Comment: Guessing the image can't be found. Try changing the url to this: background-image:url("/Assets/Images/Section.jpg");

Comment: @LukeTwomey Tried it still no luck

Comment: @LukeTwomey thats a shot in the dark :) Anyhow, if his console is empty then the image is not found. And @ Chris: his height is set in pixels.

Comment: Also, textcase on the folders and image names **is** important.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle to your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xywzx4uv/
(Note: I used another image and removed the broken comment)

```
 .starter
{
 background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1244-102-1.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 width:100%;
 height: 100px;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
}
```

It is working as intended, so there must be an error with the image-path.

Comment: This is not really an answer is it? This would have been better off as a comment imho. Also, why does everyone find it easier to go to jsfiddle? Theres an SO snippet button _right here on the editor_. So close you can even click it! Ah well.

Comment: I answered his question about "any prerequisites", so why is this no answer?

Comment: @WaKai j08691 hits the nail on the head. If you want to say 'it works', just mention it in the comments, you can even include a JS fiddle there. I won't downvote you, though, as you're just getting started, but keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @RakeshRenzous as the note says, i only changed the picture path and the broken comment. If you are totally sure that the path is correct, then please ignore the answer.

Comment: @RakeshRenzous So wait, this _solved_ your issue? Your _not-an-issue_-issue?

Comment: @somethinghere Yes it did,Thanks